# checking array strings with foreach in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I'm brand new to this so if I'm not explaining the problem as I should, please let me know!

I'm basically using Twilio Quest as a way to start learning Javascript and have gotten myself a little stuck.

The challenge is to test the conditions of an array of strings and increase the value of a variable every time a certain string appears ... then return the value of said variable at the end of the function.

Here's what I have:

```
let freightItems = ['contraband', 'clear', 'contraband', 'clear'];
freightItems.forEach(scan);

function scan(freightItems) {

    const contrabandCount = 0;

        if (freightItems.element == 'contraband') {
            contrabandCount + 1;
        }

    return contrabandCount;

}
```

The error I'm getting when I submit the code to TwilioQuest is:

> Your function returned a number, but not the value we were looking
>   for. Your function should examine every item in the input array, and
>   return the total number of times the string "contraband" appeared.

Comment: The line `contrabandCount + 1;` doesn't change the value of `contrabandCount`. You have to store the result in `contrabandCount`: `contrabandCount = contrabandCount + 1` (or `contrabandCount += 1`)

Comment: You are treating the strings as objects when you do `freightItems.element`. Also a return in `forEach` callback has nowhere to return to

Comment: What is the expected output? it's not really clear here. you're trying to count the occurrences of a word, ok, but you have to store that value... where? Right now you're not storing it anywhere (other than being wrong, as others are explaining)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple of problems in your code:

1. you should iterate over the array inside the `scan` function because you can't return `contrabandCount` variable like you are trying to. Move the `forEach` loop inside the `scan` function
2. change

   ```
   contrabandCount + 1;
   ```

   to

   ```
   contrabandCount = contrabandCount + 1;
   ```

   because you need to update the `contrabandCount` variable with the result of `contrabandCount + 1`

```js
let freightItems = ['contraband', 'clear', 'contraband', 'clear'];

function scan(freightItems) {
  let contrabandCount = 0;
  
  freightItems.forEach(str => {
    if (str === 'contraband') {
        contrabandCount = contrabandCount + 1;
    }
  })
  
  return contrabandCount;
}

console.log(scan(freightItems))
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be a solution

```js
let contrabandCount = 0;

let freightItems = ['contraband', 'clear', 'contraband', 'clear'];
freightItems.forEach(el => {
  if (el === 'contraband') {
    contrabandCount++;
  }
});

console.log(contrabandCount);
```

If you're not forced to use a forEach:

```js
let freightItems = ['contraband', 'clear', 'contraband', 'clear'];
let contrabandCount = freightItems.filter(el => el === 'contraband').length
console.log(contrabandCount);
```